# how to power a HTML5 template with codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, templates

I just purchased a HTML5 template from themeforest.com, I want to make a website using this template in codeigniter. I have been making websites using custom PHP with html templates and I have also worked on codeigniter but never used a template.

I like a template very much and instead of designing it from scratch myself, i just purchased it.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: using a template engine like smarty with codeigniter google for tutorials

Comment: I don't see big differences from what you did before, a part from having the html already done

Comment: I've done this before. Basically I just converted the html files to php files, chopped them into body templates, headers and footers and loaded them as views with data on some pages and used ajax on others. This is such abroad question on "how to do a thing". But it's really very simple.

Answer (score 0):

What you have bought is just HTML, CSS and maybe some javascript. There is absolutely nothing different about this than if you were to design and create your own HTML pages.

Treat them the same, but within codeigniter you will need to place them as views.

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-views-templating-in-codeigniter--net-25648

This should help you.